# AMD GPU Inactive in Hybrid Setup

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, amdgpu, hybrid-graphics

I built a new desktop with intel-AMD hybrid graphics and ubuntu 23.10, but I can't seem to get my AMD card to 'activate'. No output to the HDMI on the card. It is a recognized PCI device, the 'Launch using Discrete Graphics Card' option is available but does not have an effect.

Any advice or ideas to try would be helpful! Please ask if you need more info. Thanks.

#### System Info

Motherboard: GIGABYTE B660M DS3H AX DDR4
GPU: Radeon RX 6650 XT (MSI)

`lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-S GT1 [UHD Graphics 730] (rev 0c)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Video
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Alder Lake-S GT1 [UHD Graphics 730]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 23 [Radeon RX 6650 XT / 6700S / 6800S] (rev c1)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Navi 23 [Radeon RX 6650 XT]
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

#### What I've Tried

##### DRI_PRIME

When I open terminal via 'Launch using Discrete Graphics Card' I can see that `DRI_PRIME=pci-0000_03_00_0`. I even tried `export DRI_PRIME=1` and in either case `glxinfo | grep Device` outputs

```
    Device: Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics 730 (ADL-S GT1) (0x4692)
```

`vblank_mode=0 glxgears` and `glmark2` also both perform identically with and without the option.

##### VGA Switcheroo

I tried to [enable vga_switcheroo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics). `CONFIG_VGA_SWITCHEROO=y` was in `/etc/boot/config-*`, so I updated `/etc/default/grub` with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash amdgpu.modeset=1"` and restarted. -- `vgaswitcheroo` did not apppear in `/sys/kernel/debug/`, so I assume my machine does not have a 'hardware mux'... What does that mean, is that a problem?

#### Logs

`journalctl --dmesg --boot 0 --no-hostname --no-pager --grep "amdgpu"`

```
kernel: [drm] amdgpu kernel modesetting enabled.
kernel: amdgpu: CRAT table disabled by module option
kernel: amdgpu: Virtual CRAT table created for CPU
kernel: amdgpu: Topology: Add CPU node
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: Fetched VBIOS from VFCT
kernel: amdgpu: ATOM BIOS: 113-V502MECH-1OC
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: Trusted Memory Zone (TMZ) feature disabled as experimental (default)
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: VRAM: 8176M 0x0000008000000000 - 0x00000081FEFFFFFF (8176M used)
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: GART: 512M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x000000001FFFFFFF
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: AGP: 267894784M 0x0000008400000000 - 0x0000FFFFFFFFFFFF
kernel: [drm] amdgpu: 8176M of VRAM memory ready
kernel: [drm] amdgpu: 7879M of GTT memory ready.
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: STB initialized to 2048 entries
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: Will use PSP to load VCN firmware
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: RAS: optional ras ta ucode is not available
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SECUREDISPLAY: securedisplay ta ucode is not available
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: smu driver if version = 0x0000000f, smu fw if version = 0x00000013, smu fw program = 0, version = 0x003b2b00 (59.43.0)
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SMU driver if version not matched
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: use vbios provided pptable
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is initialized successfully!
kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:03:00.1: bound 0000:03:00.0 (ops amdgpu_dm_audio_component_bind_ops [amdgpu])
kernel: amdgpu: HMM registered 8176MB device memory
kernel: kfd kfd: amdgpu: Allocated 3969056 bytes on gart
kernel: kfd kfd: amdgpu: Total number of KFD nodes to be created: 1
kernel: amdgpu: Virtual CRAT table created for GPU
kernel: amdgpu: Topology: Add dGPU node [0x73ef:0x1002]
kernel: kfd kfd: amdgpu: added device 1002:73ef
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SE 2, SH per SE 2, CU per SH 8, active_cu_number 32
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring gfx_0.0.0 uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 0
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.0 uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 0
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.0 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 0
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.0 uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 0
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.0 uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 0
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.1 uses VM inv eng 7 on hub 0
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.1 uses VM inv eng 8 on hub 0
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.1 uses VM inv eng 9 on hub 0
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.1 uses VM inv eng 10 on hub 0
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring kiq_0.2.1.0 uses VM inv eng 11 on hub 0
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring sdma0 uses VM inv eng 12 on hub 0
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring sdma1 uses VM inv eng 13 on hub 0
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_dec_0 uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 8
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_enc_0.0 uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 8
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_enc_0.1 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 8
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring jpeg_dec uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 8
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: Using BACO for runtime pm
kernel: [drm] Initialized amdgpu 3.54.0 20150101 for 0000:03:00.0 on minor 1
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: not ready 1023ms after resume; waiting
...
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: not ready 65535ms after resume; giving up
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: Unable to change power state from D3cold to D0, device inaccessible
kernel: [drm:gmc_v10_0_flush_vm_hub.constprop.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Timeout waiting for VM flush hub: 0!
kernel: [drm:gmc_v10_0_flush_vm_hub.constprop.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Timeout waiting for sem acquire in VM flush!
kernel: [drm:gmc_v10_0_flush_vm_hub.constprop.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Timeout waiting for VM flush hub: 8!
kernel: [drm:gmc_v10_0_flush_vm_hub.constprop.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Timeout waiting for sem acquire in VM flush!
kernel: [drm:gmc_v10_0_flush_vm_hub.constprop.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Timeout waiting for VM flush hub: 8!
kernel: [drm:gmc_v10_0_flush_vm_hub.constprop.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Timeout waiting for VM flush hub: 0!
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: RAS: optional ras ta ucode is not available
kernel: WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 835 at drivers/gpu/drm/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_object.c:436 amdgpu_bo_free_kernel+0x122/0x150 [amdgpu]
kernel:  mt76_connac_lib kvm_intel mt76 snd_hda_core nls_iso8859_1 amdgpu snd_hwdep i915 kvm irqbypass snd_pcm mac80211 crct10dif_pclmul amdxcp polyval_clmulni iommu_v2 polyval_generic snd_seq_midi btusb ghash_clmulni_intel snd_seq_midi_event gpu_sched aesni_intel snd_rawmidi btrtl drm_suballoc_helper cmdlinepart drm_buddy drm_ttm_helper btbcm ttm btintel crypto_simd spi_nor btmtk pmt_telemetry snd_seq drm_display_helper cryptd ee1004 mei_pxp mei_hdcp mtd pmt_class cfg80211 cec rapl snd_seq_device bluetooth snd_timer rc_core i2c_i801 intel_cstate gigabyte_wmi wmi_bmof snd libarc4 drm_kms_helper ecdh_generic i2c_smbus spi_intel_pci soundcore mei_me ecc spi_intel intel_lpss_pci i2c_algo_bit mei intel_lpss idma64 joydev intel_vsec input_leds intel_hid sparse_keymap acpi_tad acpi_pad mac_hid msr parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport efi_pstore dmi_sysfs ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj hid_generic usbhid hid crc32_pclmul r8169 ahci xhci_pci realtek libahci xhci_pci_renesas video wmi
kernel: RIP: 0010:amdgpu_bo_free_kernel+0x122/0x150 [amdgpu]
kernel:  ? amdgpu_bo_free_kernel+0x122/0x150 [amdgpu]
kernel:  ? amdgpu_bo_free_kernel+0x122/0x150 [amdgpu]
kernel:  psp_rap_initialize+0x198/0x210 [amdgpu]
kernel:  psp_resume+0x182/0x290 [amdgpu]
kernel:  amdgpu_device_fw_loading+0xf8/0x2e0 [amdgpu]
kernel:  amdgpu_device_resume+0xda/0x360 [amdgpu]
kernel:  amdgpu_pmops_runtime_resume+0x84/0x100 [amdgpu]
kernel:  amdgpu_drm_ioctl+0x38/0x90 [amdgpu]
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: RAP TA initialize fail (0) status -1.
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SECUREDISPLAY: securedisplay ta ucode is not available
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resuming...
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: smu driver if version = 0x0000000f, smu fw if version = 0x00000013, smu fw program = 0, version = 0x003b2b00 (59.43.0)
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SMU driver if version not matched
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: dpm has been disabled
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resumed successfully!
kernel: WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 835 at drivers/gpu/drm/amd/amdgpu/../display/dc/dcn20/dcn20_hubbub.c:566 hubbub2_get_dchub_ref_freq+0xbb/0xe0 [amdgpu]
kernel:  mt76_connac_lib kvm_intel mt76 snd_hda_core nls_iso8859_1 amdgpu snd_hwdep i915 kvm irqbypass snd_pcm mac80211 crct10dif_pclmul amdxcp polyval_clmulni iommu_v2 polyval_generic snd_seq_midi btusb ghash_clmulni_intel snd_seq_midi_event gpu_sched aesni_intel snd_rawmidi btrtl drm_suballoc_helper cmdlinepart drm_buddy drm_ttm_helper btbcm ttm btintel crypto_simd spi_nor btmtk pmt_telemetry snd_seq drm_display_helper cryptd ee1004 mei_pxp mei_hdcp mtd pmt_class cfg80211 cec rapl snd_seq_device bluetooth snd_timer rc_core i2c_i801 intel_cstate gigabyte_wmi wmi_bmof snd libarc4 drm_kms_helper ecdh_generic i2c_smbus spi_intel_pci soundcore mei_me ecc spi_intel intel_lpss_pci i2c_algo_bit mei intel_lpss idma64 joydev intel_vsec input_leds intel_hid sparse_keymap acpi_tad acpi_pad mac_hid msr parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport efi_pstore dmi_sysfs ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj hid_generic usbhid hid crc32_pclmul r8169 ahci xhci_pci realtek libahci xhci_pci_renesas video wmi
kernel: RIP: 0010:hubbub2_get_dchub_ref_freq+0xbb/0xe0 [amdgpu]
kernel:  ? hubbub2_get_dchub_ref_freq+0xbb/0xe0 [amdgpu]
kernel:  ? hubbub2_get_dchub_ref_freq+0xbb/0xe0 [amdgpu]
kernel:  dcn30_init_hw+0x1d5/0x830 [amdgpu]
kernel:  dc_set_power_state+0x10c/0x170 [amdgpu]
kernel:  dm_resume+0xf0/0x6a0 [amdgpu]
kernel:  amdgpu_device_ip_resume_phase2+0xd0/0x210 [amdgpu]
kernel:  amdgpu_device_resume+0xe9/0x360 [amdgpu]
kernel:  amdgpu_pmops_runtime_resume+0x84/0x100 [amdgpu]
kernel:  amdgpu_drm_ioctl+0x38/0x90 [amdgpu]
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: rlc autoload: gc ucode autoload timeout
kernel: [drm:amdgpu_device_ip_resume_phase2 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* resume of IP block <gfx_v10_0> failed -110
kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: amdgpu_device_ip_resume failed (-110).
...
```

I see `Unable to change power state from D3cold to D0, device inaccessible` - maybe this is the smoking gun?

#### Update

I discovered the card does work if I have a monitor connecated **at startup**. If there's nothing plugged into the iGPU and don't leave the computer alone too long it works fine. Things tend to break if the display times out and locks. If I have the iGPU connected to monitor and leave it long enough, I still see the same problems including `Unable to change power state`.